# Office 365 E3 with Exchange Hosted Encryption (EHE)

Tags: exchange, encryption, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office, hosted-exchange

I have a client who wants to move to Office 365.

They are currently running on a trial of Office 365 E3 plan.

My staff are now also using Office 365 E3 via the internal use licenses provided as part of the MS Cloud Partner benefits.

We've search high and low, spoken to about 15 different people at Office 365 Support, as well as my local distributor's MS Product Manager, but we cannot seem to find out exactly how to purchase/subscribe to the Exchange Hosted Encryption (EHE) service, or how to configure/use it from Office 365.

Does anybody out there have any insight into how we can setup and use the EHE service?

Answer (score 0):

How to buy:

You can purchase Exchange Hosted Encryption through Microsoft partners. There are different options for purchasing, with the following licensing programs: 
 Enterprise Agreement 
 Enterprise Agreement Subscription 
 Select 
 Select Academic 
 Select U.S. Government 
 Open Value 
 Open Value Subscription 
 Campus (Higher Education) 
 School (K-12) 
 Service Provider License Agreement (SPLA)

Important to remember that EHE is a FOPE offering! To enable it you must force the "use TLS" policy in FOPE.

That being said it is currently a bit of a pain to get EHE active... not sure why -_-!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is purchased through distribution and it can be setup under O365 policies.  Many of my customers who had this under FOPE were migrated to )365 and the policies were moved as well.